# LINQ - using a selected collection between methods/classes

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-objects

After a lot of searching I wasn't able to find anything that clearly describes why I'm seeing this behavior (and I presume it's something very simple I'm missing - I'm still very much a beginner :)

I have a method (RefreshFilter) that takes an object (rfp) as a parameter.  rfp has a property named 'Items' that is of type List.

I have 2 calls to RefreshFilter that look like this:

```
rfp = RefreshFilter(rfp, FilteredBy.Category)
rfp = RefreshFilter(rfp, FilteredBy.Industry)
```

Here is the RefreshFilter method:

```
public FilterParams RefreshFilterList(FilterParams rfp, FilteredBy filteredBy)
{
    using (myEntity context as new myEntity())
    {
        itemsInCategory = (from i in context.items
                           join ic in context.ItemsCategories on i.Id equals ic.items.id
                           where ic.Categories.Id == '52'
                           select i).ToList<items>();

        rfp.Items = rfp.Items.Intersect(itemsInCategory).ToList<items>();
    }
    return rfp;
}
```

The first call to RefreshFilter(...) works just fine and returns a FilterParams object with a .items property that contains an intersected list.

The second call to RefreshFilter(...) **always** returns a FilterParams object with a .items property containing an list of **0 elements** (which is not expected since I know there are matching elements in the lists).

Through some testing, I believe I have been able to narrow this down to being related to the context that rfp.Items is set in.  However I was always under the impression that the proper way to share collections between contexts was to select them into collection objects and pass these objects around, but it seems that these objects are still tied to their initial context in some way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public FilterParams RefreshFilterList(FilterParams rfp, FilteredBy filteredBy)
{
    using (myEntity context as new myEntity())
    {
        itemIdsInCategory = (from i in context.items
                           join ic in context.ItemsCategories on i.Id equals ic.items.id
                           where ic.Categories.Id == '52'
                           select i.Id).ToList<int>();

        rfp.Items = rfp.Items.Where(i => itemIdsInCategory.Contains(i.Id)).ToList<Item>();
    }
    return rfp;
}
```

Here we are only comparing the unique Ids of the items (int in this case) which could provide a performance benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly (and makes more sense too)!

Comment: After further testing this still leads to an issue with passing the collection between methods.  When I execute a LINQ query against rfp in the second call to RefreshFilter() (i.e. ...'from i in **rfp.Items** rather than in context.Items) I receive an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on tc.items.id.  My intent is to be able to pass the rfp object between methods cleanly, but it seems that once rfp.Items is set initially it is not able to be queried outside of the original method that set it's value (presumably because of the context used).

Comment: I should clarify that in my first call to RefreshFilter() rfp.Items is filled/initiated in this way:  rfp.Items = (from i in context.items select i).ToList<Items>().

Comment: The answer provided was the the correct answer to the question. The additional mistake being made due to the fact that you can't join between an in memory list and a queriable object (totally overlooked by me).